# Filtering number of features in GeoServer using SLD?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, point, sld, function

I have published point file in geoserver  from postgis table as store. I had huge data in my table(rows) and the data will keep udate daily (at least one point for one day). Now I want to show only the last 10 points added.

How do I restrict the data using Geoserver SLD Function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I would try to separate data store access/publishing from layer styling.
You could create a [SQL View](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html) for the datastore, effectively adding a new layer with the query result table. The query will execute each time the layer is requested, the SLD style can be applied as usual.